# Assign a License (Microsoft Graph API)

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to assign a license in C# via Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0

Parameters:

> **addLicenses** (AssignedLicense collection)
>
> A collection of assignedLicense objects that specify the licenses to add. You can
> disable plans associated with a license by setting the disabledPlans
> property on an assignedLicense object.
>
> **removeLicenses** (Guid collection)
>
> A collection of GUIDs that identify the licenses to remove.

Here is my code ...

```
var userQuery = await client.Users
  .Request()
  .Filter("userPrincipalName eq 'xxx@xxx.de'")
  .GetAsync();
var user = userQuery.FirstOrDefault();

var skus = await client.SubscribedSkus.Request().GetAsync();

do
{
  foreach (var sku in skus)
  {

    AssignedLicense aLicense = new AssignedLicense { SkuId = sku.SkuId };

    IList<AssignedLicense> licensesToAdd = new AssignedLicense[] { aLicense };
    IList<Guid> licensesToRemove = new Guid[] { };

    try
    {
      client.Users[user.Id].AssignLicense(licensesToAdd, licensesToRemove);
    }
  }
}
while (skus.NextPageRequest != null && (skus = await skus.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
```

I don't get an error, but it does not work. The user has no license ...

Comment: What is ***SubscribedSkus*** ?

Comment: Get the list of commercial subscriptions that an organization has acquired.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot something here:

```
client.Users[user.Id].AssignLicense(licensesToAdd, licensesToRemove);
```

I think it should be:

```
await client.Users[user.Id].AssignLicense(licensesToAdd, licensesToRemove).Request().PostAsync();
```

PS:

You can get the user with less code like:

```
var userQuery = await client.Users["xxx@xxx.de"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: `client.Users vs client.Me` ? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/a675be0a8b2c3d500596871edef38427e691aa3e/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/UserTests.cs#L302